# Cassandra Data Model Design

Tags: cassandra

Suppose I have have a huge list of movies categorized by genres. Users can vote for movies, and each movie can be in multiple genres.

What is a good way to store this in Cassandra if I want to present the top X movies per category? Please ignore other use cases as I can have other column families as required (like presenting detailed movie information).

**Action**

1. Movie A
2. Movie B
3. Movie C

**Comedy**

1. Movie D
2. Movie E
3. Movie A

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have presented -I say that you only gave requirements to create a single column family.

The columns would be - movie name, category, and any other attributes about the movie.

It is quite common to create several column families with different structure that are like 'materialized views' of original column family.

In Cassandra you design column families based on how the application is going to use it.   So, you design your queries first then you design the column family to support it.

Comment: Yes, I want some guidance on how to design this single column family. What I am trying to ask is how will this column family look like. For example, I could say that my column family will have a composite primary key based on genre, number_of_votes and movie_name, and use `with clustering order by (number_of_votes desc)` that way I can say, `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genre = 'action' LIMIT 5` to get the top 5 action movies. The problem with this is I would need to make one query per genre, and most importantly, I cannot update the number of votes since it is part of the primary key.